# Make List<List<string>> suitable for binding

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, .net-4.0, infragistics

I have a `List<List<string>>` where the outer list will be the rows for a grid and the inner list the column values.

How can I wrap the `List<List<string>>` so it's a suitable DataSource for the grid, which accepts `IList` or `IBindingList`?

Effectively I want it to be seen as a `List<MyObject>` with the `MyObject` class having exposing the strings as public properties for binding.

I can't change the list and it can have a very big number of rows so copying the data wouldn't be ideal.

A simple example of the difference is the following code with a `DataGridView` dropped on a `WinForm`:

```
 public class SupplierEntry
    {
        public string SupplierCode
        {
            get
            {
                return "SUPPLIERCODE";
            }
        }

        public string SupplierTitle
        {
            get
            {
                return "SUPPLIERTITLE";
            }
        }
    }

    private void Test()
    {
        List<string> supplierEntryString = new List<string>();
        supplierEntryString.Add("SUPPLIERCODE");
        supplierEntryString.Add("SUPPLIERTITLE");            

        List<List<string>> supplierListStrings = new List<List<string>>();
        supplierListStrings.Add(supplierEntryString);

        List<SupplierEntry> supplierListObjects = new List<SupplierEntry>();

        SupplierEntry supplierEntryObject = new SupplierEntry();
        supplierListObjects.Add(supplierEntryObject);

        //this can't handle the nested collections, instead showing a Capacity and Count column 
        dataGridView1.DataSource = supplierListStrings;

        //this works giving you a supplier code and title column
        //dataGridView1.DataSource = supplierListObjects;
    }
```

Comment: By 'grid', do you mean the DataGridView?

Comment: Infragistics UltraGrid and UltraCombo (which dropped part is effectively also a grid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting the DataSource of a DataGridView, the DataGridView will treat the supplied object as an `IList<something>`, where for each `something` it will use reflection to find all the public readable properties. The public readable properties of a `List<string>` are Capacity and Count.

In order to get your strings to appear in the DataGridView they must be presented as properties. You can do this at least three ways: Make your own class (as you have already done with `SupplierEntry`), use a `Tuple`, or use an anonymous type.

A compromise that would allow you to use your source `List<List<string>>` without copying any data would be to provide a wrapper class which just presents the data as properties:

```
// Provide named properties which really just read elements 
// from the List<string> provided with the constructor
public class ListBasedRecord {
    public string SupplierName { get { return source[0]; } }
    public string SupplierCode { get { return source[1]; } }
    private List<string> source;
    public ListBasedRecord(List<string> source) { this.source = source; }
}

private void ListTest() {
    // ... same as above, you get your List<List<string>> ...
    // Succinctly create a SupplierEntryWrapper for each "record" in the source
    var wrapperList = supplierListStrings
                      .Select(x => new SupplierEntryWrapper(x)).ToList();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = wrapperList;
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, this is just adding a tiny amount of memory per string list?

Comment: You could check with a profiler, but it should only be a few bytes per record. The only _data_ attached to each `ListBasedRecord` is an object reference (the private field `source`), which only takes 4 bytes -- the equivalent of a 2-character string.